# Scheduling wordpress posts

Tags: scheduled-posts

I'd like to schedule 1 post to be *published* every day until the total post count runs out, before cycling the process over again. Each of these posts must expire (revert to "*draft*" or "*archived*") after 7 days of "*published*" age. All of these posts would be under a custom post type.

In total I will create 200 posts. All 200 posts must be published consecutively before the cycle begins again at post #1. Consequently every 7 days at a specified time (00:00) one new post will be published, and one post of 7 days age will be unpublished.

**Does anyone have any pointers on how I might execute this?** I'm familiar with a few plugins such as 'WP Scheduled Posts Pro' by WPDeveloper, but I would need to manually go through all 200 posts to schedule each date, and then update their publish/unpublish dates every year via SQL (fastest method instead of going through each post individually). This plugin also wouldn't allow me to increase the amount of posts without disrupting the existing schedule. The plugin also has way more features than required.

Comment: I think this might be easiest to write code to do this yourself, unless you can find a more suitable plugin. You just need to write a small plugin with a daily scheduled job, and you should be able to update the post state through WordPress's get and update post functions without having to write SQL yourself. You'll probably need to store where you're up to, and what order the posts are in, in wp_options.

Comment: @Rup I was hoping some of the work might have been done already, but you're probably right in that I'd have to tackle this one myself. If you have any pointers on where I might want to start, I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks :)